# How to detect numbers in a page via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, and it works for English and Persian languages but now I need to detect numbers.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("body, div, p, a, b, strong, bold, font, span, td").filter(function () {
        return $(this).children(":not(.word)").length == 0
    }).each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = $(this).text().replace(/\S+/g, function (word) {
            return "<span class='word'>" + word + "</span>";
        });

        $(".word", this).filter(isEnglish).addClass('english');

        $(".word", this).filter(isPersian).addClass('persian');
    });
    function isEnglish() {
        return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) < 255;
    }
    function isPersian() {
        return $(this).text().charCodeAt(0) > 255;
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I would suspect a lot of languages are above char code 255, not just Persian.

Comment: @naomik Yes, It works for Persian and other languages. but how about numbers?

Comment: So, you're createing a `isNumber()` function that should return true/false on whether or not the text is a number?  Is that right?

Comment: @SuperScript yes I use different classes for Persian, English languages and Numbers ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
function isNumber() {
    return !isNaN($(this).text() * 1);
}
```

That will take the text and attempt to turn it into a number.  If it succeeds, it will return a number, otherwise it will return `NaN`.  The `isNaN` function tests to see if `NaN` was returned, and returns true/false.  That is then inversed to tell you whether or not the text is a valid number.

Or, the jQuery way to do it is to `return $.isNumeric($(this).text());`.